# Issue sharing array between goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I am trying to solve this golang exercise https://github.com/loong/go-concurrency-exercises/tree/master/1-producer-consumer.

I guess I am close to the solution but I am getting a deadlock error

```
davecheney      tweets about golang
beertocode      does not tweet about golang
ironzeb         tweets about golang
beertocode      tweets about golang
vampirewalk666  tweets about golang
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

here is my code

```golang
func producer(stream Stream) (tweets []*Tweet) {
    for {
        tweet, err := stream.Next()
        if err == ErrEOF {
            return tweets
        }

        tweets = append(tweets, tweet)
    }
}

func consumer(tweets []*Tweet) {
    for _, t := range tweets {
            if t.IsTalkingAboutGo() {
            fmt.Println(t.Username, "\ttweets about golang")
        } else {
            fmt.Println(t.Username, "\tdoes not tweet about golang")
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    stream := GetMockStream()

    data := make(chan []*Tweet)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(3)
    // Producer
    go func() {
        tweets := producer(stream)
        data <- tweets
    }()



    // Consumer
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        tweets := <-data
        consumer(tweets)
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("Process took %s\n", time.Since(start))
}
```

Where y solution is failing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deadlock happened because you pass `3` to `wg.Add(3)`, which means creating 3 waiting groups but you only need 1.

Solution is replacing `wg.Add(3)` with `wg.Add(1)`.

Check my demo code [here](https://go.dev/play/p/ByXIsRyzpiu)

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your answer.
Sadly, the exercise is expecting to get the performance enhanced but with your solution the program took the same time than without go routines to run.

And this is something that I am asking for my self  from the first time: how to the run time could enhanced by running producer and consumer concurrently when both are not only independent but also one should wait for the other to start.

But the exercise states clearly that the solution should make use go concurrency and the running time is expected to be lower by modifying just main function...

Comment: Ignore my previous message, it worked fine.